# Wireshark / tshark print MAC address list of BLE Advertising Report

Tags: bluetooth, wireshark, tshark

I have started `sudo hcitool lescan --passive --duplicate`

and `sudo tcpdump -i bluetooth0 -w cap.pcap`

Now viewing this in Wireshark I get a lot of LE Advertising Repots

[image]

However in the colums I can't select MAC address and also in the statistics menu I've tried some options, but still didn't get a list of different MAC addresses present in this capture file.

[image]

A tshark command for getting these addresses would be great, but Wireshark is also ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer
`tshark -r cap.cap -T fields -e bthci_evt.bd_addr | sort | uniq`

[image]